# Sri Bhuvaneshwari scriptural references?

Tags: devi, reference-request, bhuvaneshwari

Where can the first historical references of Sri Bhuvaneshvari be found? Is there any reference that precedes the Mahavidyas?

Comment: I doubt we would find reference of all 10 mahavidyas other than Tantra. There is sure mentioning of "bhu" devi and she is also known as bhuvaneshwari. But the Mahavidya one's consort is Shiva while Bhu devi consort is Vishnu. So they are not same.

Comment: Searching about Carcika Goddess i found the Etymology of the name Bhubaneswar which is the anglicisation of the Odia name "Bhubaneswara"(ଭୁବନେଶ୍ୱର), derived from the word Tribhubaneswara (ତ୍ରିଭୁବନେଶ୍ୱର), which literally means the Lord (Eeswara) of the Three Worlds (Tribhubana), which refers to Shiva.

Comment: Now the question would be to know , and most probably is, if the root of Bhuba or Bhuva has the same meaning.  But i think it has in this context. Unfortunatelly i didn’t found any sources yet.